# Identical rmd files create different latex files when run on two computers

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

When my colleague and I run the same Rmd file on our respective computers they produce different .tex files. This is a problem, because the tex-file my computer produces doesn't compile. Apparently there is some invisible local setting that is different between our computers but what could it be? I updated all the Rpackages I use but to no avail.

The Rmd file starts with

```
output:
   bookdown::pdf_document2:
     keep_tex: yes
     toc: false
```

And both of us compile it by simply hitting the knit-button in Rstudio.

Noticeable differences in the tex-files are:

- extra linebreaks in different places
- a line that is commented out in the rmd-file (`<!-- blabla -->`) appears in my tex-file, not in his, but some other out-commented lines appear in neither (as they should)
- at the end of lines in tables there is a `\strut` inserted in my tex-file but not in his
- Section heads read `\hypertaget{blabla}` in his file but not mine

For none of these difference I can find any place in the Rmd-file where any choice w.r.t to this is made - apparently some local settings file I am not aware of is used in the process??

Please let me know if you need more information.

EDIT: we found a partial answer and full solution, but I am still interested in what the underlying mechanism is. It turned out that I was using an older version of Rstudio. (It took me long to find that out because the `check for updates` tool in Rstudio kept telling me that I was using the newest version, but that is a separate issue.) Using the same version of Rstudio we get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation from `Rmd` to `tex` has multiple steps:

- All the code chunks are extracted and executed via `knitr`, resulting in a `md` file.
- The `md` file is translated to `tex` via `pandoc`.

For most people `pandoc` comes bundled with RStudio. So when you updated that, you got a more recent `pandoc` version. You can test for the used `pandoc` version with `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()`.